# Javascript toSource() method not working

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a "Object doesn't support this property or method error", does anyone know why?

I do have values plugged into userId, fname, lname, oname, sam, hasAccess

```
function Employee(id, fname, lname, oname, sam, access) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.oname = oname
    this.sam = sam;
    this.access = access;
}

var emp = new Employee(userId, fname, lname, oname, sam, hasAccess);

var jsonstuff = emp.toSource(); //Breaking here
```

Although this link says its possible http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toSource_date.asp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`toSource()` does not work in Internet Explorer or Safari. It is Gecko-only. See [Implementing Mozilla's toSource() method in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer) for alternatives.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Safari! The browser world isn't just Firefox and IE.

Comment: @Vince: If your boss is that incompetent, try to explain to him that making sure that it works outside IE and FF will result in less maintenance work next time IE is upgraded. It will also make the IE and FF users much less annoyed with your company when they browse the site from their cell phone (no matter if it is an iPhone, a Nokia or something else without IE).

Comment: Don't forget Chrome is really getting into the fight. Leaving Safari+Chrome+Opera aside, you could be leaving 15% of the share (depending on your website market). Like an example, see: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: @Vince: 1998 called, it wants its rhetoric back. Safari and Chrome share the Webkit rendering engine; together, it's a considerable share of the market. Also, if it works in FF, it's 90% chance it'll work in Safari,Chrome,Opera,etc. (not in IE though, that's more like a 50% chance)

Answer (score 9):

Try using a [JSON serializer](http://www.json.org/js.html) instead.  `toSource` is Mozilla specific and not supported by IE.

If you are just debugging then your best bet is going to be to [install Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and use console.dir(emp); to print the contents of an object to the console window.

Update: Just notice that on the [link you posted](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toSource_date.asp) it says, "Note: This method does not work in Internet Explorer!"  And on the [MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) it says "Non-Standard".

Comment: Oops! sorry guys didnt see that

Comment: There are 5 different implementations of JSON Serializer from that GitHub link.  Can you give an example alternative of this code: alert(obj.toSource())

Comment: Try `alert(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Answer (score 5):

You can either call toString instead, or put in a condition like this...

```
var jsonstuff = (emp.toSource) ? emp.toSource() : emp.toString();
```

**EDIT:**

Since this is not working for you, you might want to use [JSON.stringify()](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst not recommended (to extend native JS Objects), during development you could use:

```
Object.prototype.toSource 
    || (Object.prototype.toSource = function(){return JSON.stringify(this);})

c = {a:100}
//>Object
c.toSource()
//>"{"a":100}"
```

cheers!

Comment: What about functions and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an existing library or plugin:

- ExtJs: http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.util.JSON
- jQuery: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
- Dojo: http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojox.json.ref.toJson