# How can I view array structure in JavaScript with alert()?

Tags: javascript

How can I view the structure of an array in JavaScript using `alert()`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should install FireBug and use `console.log` -- it's great for introspection of JavaScript objects.

Comment: What do you mean with array structure? You can loop through the array and alert each value.

Comment: @ Deniz Dogan by console.log do you mean shift+R and option "console" ?

Comment: @Deniz - `console.debug` would actually work better.

Comment: @Tim by structure i mean the index and the value, the "raw" view of array like in PHP printf

Comment: @Bears will eat you - How i can view this console.debug?

Comment: Like Deniz said, you need to use a debugger. If you're using IE 8, there's one built in; if you're using Firefox, you should install Firebug. If you don't understand how to use a debugger, look [here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Using_Firebug).

Comment: i think it's like this console.log(array)

Answer (score 124):

A very basic approach is `alert(arrayObj.join('\n'))`, which will display each array element in a row.

Comment: This works great. Replace "arrayObj" with the name of your array. So if your array is named myArray, this is your line of code: `alert(myArray.join('\n'));`

Answer (score 54):

**EDIT:** Firefox and Google Chrome now have a built-in `JSON` object, so you can just say `alert(JSON.stringify(myArray))` without needing to use a jQuery plugin.  This is not part of the Javascript language spec, so you shouldn't rely on the `JSON` object being present in all browsers, but for debugging purposes it's incredibly useful.

I tend to use the [jQuery-json plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) as follows:

```
alert( $.toJSON(myArray) );
```

This prints the array in a format like

```
[5, 6, 7, 11]
```

However, for debugging your Javascript code, I **highly** recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)  It actually comes with a Javascript console, so you can type out Javascript code for any page and see the results.  Things like arrays are already printed in the human-readable form used above.

Firebug also has a debugger, as well as screens for helping you view and debug your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 31):

pass  your js array to the function below and it will do the same as php print_r() function

```
 alert(print_r(your array));  //call it like this

function print_r(arr,level) {
var dumped_text = "";
if(!level) level = 0;

//The padding given at the beginning of the line.
var level_padding = "";
for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
    for(var item in arr) {
        var value = arr[item];

        if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
            dumped_text += print_r(value,level+1);
        } else {
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
        }
    }
} else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
    dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
}
return dumped_text;
}
```

Comment: this function make firefox crashed with parsing a UI sortable array.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `alert(arrayObj.toSource());`

Comment: Works under Firefox, but not under Safari or MSIE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101584/javascript-tosource-method-not-working

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend using toString().

Ex. `alert(array.toString())`, or `console.log(array.toString())`

Answer (score 4):

For readability purposes you can use: `alert(JSON.stringify(someArrayOrObj, '', 4));`

More about [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

**Example:**

```js
let user = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
    roles: {
        isAdmin: false,
        isEditor: true,
    },
};

alert(JSON.stringify(user, '', 4));
```

**Output:**

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "roles": {
        "isAdmin": false,
        "isEditor": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is for debugging purposes, I would advise you use a JavaScript debugger such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It will let you view the entire contents of arrays and much more, including modifying array entries and stepping through code.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to show with an alert() the content of an array of objects, i recomend you to define in the object the method toString() so with a simple alert(MyArray); the full content of the array will be shown in the alert.

Here is an example:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Defininf the Point object
function Point(CoordenadaX, CoordenadaY) {
    // Sets the point coordinates depending on the parameters defined
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 0:
            this.x = null;
            this.y = null;
            break;
        case 1:
            this.x = CoordenadaX;
            this.y = null;
            break;
        case 2:
            this.x = CoordenadaX;
            this.y = CoordenadaY;
            break;
    }
    // This adds the toString Method to the point object so the 
    // point can be printed using alert();
    this.toString = function() {
        return " (" + this.x + "," + this.y + ") ";
    };
 }
```

Then if you have an array of points:

```
var MyArray = [];
MyArray.push ( new Point(5,6) );
MyArray.push ( new Point(7,9) );
```

You can print simply calling:

```
alert(MyArray);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that will convert and format this array as string. Even better: use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for debugging instead of alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Better use Firebug (chrome console etc) and use console.dir()

Answer (score -5):

```
alert($("#form_id").serialize());
```

Comment: The question is tagged `javascript` which says "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected". Even if that wasn't the case… the question is asking about an array, not an HTML form.