# How to print array data in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, user-interface, alert

```
saveData: function()
    {

        var element = $('input');
        for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++)
        {
            //alert($(element[i]).val());
            var p=new Array($(element[i]).val());
        }
        alert(p);

    },
```

How to print array data in alert.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: It should work as it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print content of JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Comment: i want to show all for loop data in alert but it is not showing all for loop data in alert.Please help me.

Comment: If you are using firefox browser, make use of console.log()

Comment: Please follow the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006644/how-can-i-view-array-structure-in-javascript-with-alert

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an array and then push all the values to it, instead you are resetting it in the loop

```
var element = $('input');
var p = element.map(function () {
    return this.value
}).get();
alert(JSON.stringify(p));//or alert(p);
```

changing your code will be

```
var element = $('input');
var p = [];
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    p.push($(element).eq(i).val());
}
alert(JSON.stringify(p));//or alert(p)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use javascript **toString()** function to get result

```
var array = ["a","b","c"];
```

**solution:**

```
alert(array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To display array values properly try this :

```
saveData: function()
    {
        var p=new Array();
        var element = $('input');
        for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++)
        {
            //alert($(element[i]).val());
            p[0] = $(element[i]).val();
        }
        alert(p.join("\n"));

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you could just

```
for(i=0; i<p.length; ++i){
    alert(p[i]);
}
```

so if p is an array containing `["one","two","three"]` your browser will alert `"one", "two"` and then `"three"` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript **forEach()** function to get result

```
var array = ["a","b","c"];
```

**solution:**

```
array.forEach(function(data){alert(data)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join()`.

It converts each array element into a string.
It acts much like **toString()**, moreover you can determine the separator.

```
var arr = ["HTML","CSS","JS"]; 
...
alert(arr.join(' - '));
```