# JSON string not returned properly in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

```
String json1 = new Gson().toJson(list);
System.out.println(json1);
request.getSession().setAttribute("json1", json1);
```

I checked the logs it prints string like : `["090856","056986"]`

In JSP I wrote something line below in script

```
var n = '<%= session.getAttribute("json1") %>';
alert(n);
```

The alert displayed `090856,056986`.

why such behaviour should not it display `["090856","056986"]`.

sometimes it also appears like this too

[image: Alert Message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view array structure in javascript with alert()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006644/how-can-i-view-array-structure-in-javascript-with-alert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your your code. **alert** is modifying the string while showing.

1. Use `console.log(n)` to test your json string.
2. Or use **JSON.stringify** function

   ```
   alert(JSON.stringify(n));
   ```

Comment: @BineetKumarNayak welcome. Consider accepting an answer if it solves your problem. It will be helpful for others who face the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal behaviour.

You can try directly in chrome console.

1. List item
2. Go to chrome
3. Press F12
4. Go to Console tab
5. Enter command : alert( ["090856","056986"]);
6. As a result you have the following alert box

[image]

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But he supposedly enclosed it in single quotes.

Comment: sometimes it appears like ["090856","056986"] in the alert