# toSource in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Javascript toSource() method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101584/javascript-tosource-method-not-working)
>   [Implementing Mozilla’s toSource() method in Internet Explorer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer)

Is there an alternative method toSource for internet explorer?

Comment: Better Duplicate - [Implementing Mozilla's toSource() method in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toSource` is non standard and works in the gecko engine only, so will not work in chrome, safari *or* IE.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101584/javascript-tosource-method-not-working) SO question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same as `toSource()` but [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) has `JSON.stringify()` which will convert a JavaScript object to JSON.  This won't convert everything that `.toSource()` will.  It doesn't for instance deal with functions.