# Searching for objects in JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I search for the property of an object in an array without using `for` loops in JavaScript?

If the array is a simple one I can use `array.indexOf(value)` to get the index, but what if the array is an array of objects? Other than looping any other way?

For example, `ar = [{x,y},{p,q},{u,v}]`. If searched for `v`, it should return the array index as 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for a value in an array typically requires a [sequential search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), which requires you to loop over each item until you find a match.

```
function search(ar, value) {
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    for (j in ar[i]) {  
      if (ar[i][j] === value) return i;
    }
  }
}

search([{'x': 'y'}, {'p': 'q'}, {'u': 'v'}], 'v'); // returns 2;
```

Comment: yep , that way I understand. I thought if there is some inbuilt functions to do the search , like we can sort an array depending on the objects property using array.sort() and compare function.

Comment: @sat: Not really. These are the methods available for Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array. In JavaScript 1.6 there is the `filter()` method, but that would still be too complex for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[Searching for objects in JavaScript arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624741/searching-for-objects-in-javascript-arrays/3624761#3624761)

```
javascript:
   /* quick fix naive short solution to be posted soon */
   /* array of objects with primitive property values only and no wrinkles */
```

.

```
javascript:
   alert(
      JSON.stringify(
         [{x:1,y:2},,,{p:"q"},{u:{},vx:[],x:{y:{},x:5}}]
             ) . match(/"x":/g)
    )
```

and

```
javascript:   /*  Does the need to fortify this code imply JSON is stronger?  */
   alert(                                             /*  See wrinkles below  */
      [{x:1,y:2},,,{p:"q"},{u:{},vx:[],x:{y:{},x:5}}] . toSource() .
 /*
         match(/({|,)\s*x:/g) . join() . replace(/({|,)\s*x:/g,"x:")
   finds `x:,x:,x:`
 */
         replace(/(({|,)\s*)([^,{:]*):/g,'$1"$3":') . match(/"x":/g)
    )
```

find `"x":,"x":,"x":`.

Specific property found, done deal?

Hint, hint (but must be appropriately attenuated and amputated for nested animals):

```
javascript:
    alert(
        JSON.stringify([{x:1,y:2},{p:"q"},{u:{},v:[],x:{y:{},x:5}}]) . 
             match(/"[^"]*":/g)
    )
```

finds `"x":,"y":,"p":,"u":,"v":,"x":,"y":,"x":`  (all properties - Done Now?)

More (a lot more) brain strain pain will find `x:`values and index of array positions (Hint count top level `,`'s).

Amputate and attenuate hint (only removes nested array and object `,`'s, see wrinkles):

```
javascript:debug=false;
   animal=[
      {x:1,y:2},,,{p:"q"},
         [ {u:{},vx:[,,], x:{y:{xx:''},x:5} }, "hmmm comma x colon \" monster" ],
   ];
   animal=animal.toSource().replace(/\[(.*)]/,"$1");
/*  */ if(debug){
   alert(animal);
   animal=animal.replace(/\[([^[\]]*)\]/g,
               function(a,b,c,d){alert([a,b,c,d].join("\n\n"));return a});
   while(animal.search(/\{.*\}|\[.*\]/)>-1){
      animal=animal.replace(/\{([^{}]*)\}|\[(.*)\]/g,
         function(a,b,c,d){alert([a,"\n",b,"\n",c]);return b.replace(/,/g,";")});
      alert(animal); }
/*  */   }

  /* the while loops on nesting depth not top array length */
   while(animal.search(/\{.*\}|\[.*\]/)>-1)
      animal=animal.replace(/\{([^{}]*)\}|\[(.*)\]/g,       /* implicit g loop */
                  function(a,b,c,d){return (b+c).replace(/,/g," ")}); /* ditto */
   alert(animal);    /* as opposed to a non-lert animal? */
```

Wrinkles:

- `.toSource()` IS stronger (but ... see above) and handles more situations than `JSON`
   ref: [Implementing Mozilla's toSource() method in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer/5628008#5628008)
- what if there are monsters with strings containing:

  1. `,`'s . . . as in . . . `[",,or",,{p:"1,2,3,"}]`
  2. `{x:...}` or `{"x":...}` . . . as in . . . `['{"x":...}'," and ","{x:...}",,]`
       (which will screw up the above coding using either `JSON` or `toSource`)
  3. nested monsters
  4. other monstrosities are mere chimeras ... not paid enough to do or prove