# javascript find objects based on search terms

Tags: javascript, search, node.js, underscore.js

I need to search an array of objects with an object of search terms and get the index of results in an array.

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Mary",
    gender: "female",
    country: "USA",
    orientation: "straight",
    colorChoice: "red",
    shoeSize: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Henry",
    gender: "male",
    country: "USA",
    orientation: "straight",
    colorChoice: "red",
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    colorChoice: "yellow",
    shoeSize: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    gender: "female",
    orientation: "gay",
    colorChoice: "red",
  }
]
```

Now I need to search the array for:

```
{
  gender: "female"
}
```

and get result:

```
[ 0, 3 ]
```

The search object can be any length:

```
{
  gender: "female",
  colorChoice: "red"
}
```

What's the cleanest and most performant way to search the array?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624741/searching-for-objects-in-javascript-arrays

Comment: You should get [0, 3] from the array you present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the idea:

```
function getFemales(myArr){
 var i = myArr.length, ret = [];
 while (i--){
  if ('gender' in myArr[i] && myArr[i].gender === 'female') {
    ret.push(i);
  }
 }
 return ret.sort();
}
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRXqc/)

And more generic:

```
function findInElements(elArray, label, val){
 var i = elArray.length, ret = [];
 while (i--){
  if (label in elArray[i] && elArray[i][label] === val) {
    ret.push(i);
  }
 }
 return ret.sort();
}
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRXqc/1)

Comment: Any reason you traverse the array in reverse?

Comment: It's quicker.See http://devpro.it/examples/loopsbench/ or http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/04/30/optimizing-javascript-for-extreme-performance-and-low-memory-consumption/

Comment: Thats pretty damn clever, since the type juggeling makes sure the while stops when i <= 0! You'd have to change your i-- to --i though :)

Comment: using --i I would miss element 0. In that case I'd have to use `(--i>=0)`. It's not significantly faster, see http://jsperf.com/loop-descendening

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
function searchArray(fields, arr)
{
    var result = [];            //Store the results

    for(var i in arr)           //Go through every item in the array
    {
        var item = arr[i];
        var matches = true;     //Does this meet our criterium?

        for(var f in fields)    //Match all the requirements
        {
            if(item[f] != fields[f])    //It doesnt match, note it and stop the loop.
            {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(matches)
            result.push(item);  //Add the item to the result
    }

    return result;
}
```

For example:

```
console.log(searchArray({
  gender: "female",
  colorChoice: "red"
},[
  {
    name: "Mary",
    gender: "female",
    country: "USA",
    orientation: "straight",
    colorChoice: "red",
    shoeSize: 7
  },
  {
    name: "Henry",
    gender: "male",
    country: "USA",
    orientation: "straight",
    colorChoice: "red",
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    colorChoice: "yellow",
    shoeSize: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    gender: "female",
    orientation: "gay",
    colorChoice: "red",
  }
]));
```

Comment: You can edit the function to return the indexes (i) of the array too, just push that on the results array instead of the item.