# Reading csv data to create chart

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to create gauge chart from csv data. Following function works well but it consider one char as `string` input. I believe this part decide how many words to be read from csv

```
hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
            vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
```

It reads this short of data only:

```
Category,' '
E,24
m,34
m,0
y,10
y,6
r,6
```

My actual data that I want to read is:

```
Engine,24
min,34
max,0
yellowFrom,10
yellowTo,6
redFrom,6
redTo,0
```

Can someone please tell me where I need improvement?

```
function drawChart() {
       $.get("Chart2-data.csv", function(csvString) {
          // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
          view.setColumns([0,1]);
         var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
         };
        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
      }
```

Entire  code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["gauge"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
       // grab the CSV
       $.get("Chart2-data.csv", function(csvString) {
          // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        alert(arrayData);
          // this new DataTable object holds all the data
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

          // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
          view.setColumns([0,1]);

         // set chart options
         var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
         };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gauge" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I faced this kind of problem while processing csv data. I think this is due to encoding problems. You must use the same encoding in the CSV and HTML/PHP

Comment: @PatarticsMilán: thanks, can you please elaborate, which encoding you talking here?

Comment: The file encoding, HTML encoding and the IO stream encoding. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17394539/2190252) is maybe related to your problem, except it is python.

Comment: @PatarticsMilán: thanks again. But updating enocoding to UTF-8 in both html csv does not make any change ..

Comment: Maybe you could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401182/2190252)

Answer (score 1):

Things where =ok,
Just remove this part:

```
title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
```

And add levels in csv data

```
label,value
Engine,24
min,34
max,0
yellowFrom,10
yellowTo,6
redFrom,6
```

It will work nice