# Converting a Javascript Object with Functions into a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I came across a situation today where I needed a single Javascript file to be accessible through HTTP. The actual program was running with NodeJS and was outside of the /home/ directory.

The reason I was trying to access the javascript file was it has a list of functions that I use often, and wanted to utilize them with PhantomJS (essentially injecting it into a different website).

I was able to get it to work by moving the entire node into an accessible folder and having htaccess deny access to everything except 1 file, but I am curious if anyone would know:

Would it be possible to take an entire object (functions and preset values) and output them as a string (same as if you navigated to a file.js page). This way I could create an HTTP page, send the proper headers and essentially create an accessible JS page.

I looked around but couldn't find any information on actually outputting a object verbatim.

Comment: See the last one answer from [Converting an object to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Comment: Awesome! If you can put that into an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Thanks, but it is already answered. Let's say it's kind of duplicate :-)

Comment: it could help someone find it in the future tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer from user *Houshalter* to the question [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string).

All answers provide different examples how to convert object without function to string. But he explains how to do that with object which contains also functions.