# object Object convert into a string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

How can I turn [object Object] to a string so I can see what's actually in the array. I tried `toString()` but that produced the same result as before

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(myVar)  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-variable-is-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: @Sudhir I would rather point to the question about debugging in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with the method [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) :

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

Or with [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) (visible in your debugger javascript, like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)) :

```
 console.log(yourObject);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pEp44/)

Comment: `console.log` with `JSON.stringify` will look horrible at the end. Don't mix them up if you don't really need to do it.

Comment: The OP just need to see his object. `console.log` is good enough.