# Node JS How to Convert String into Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

#### The exampleCode  is:

```
// 4. execute tower.init latter read from bellow (1)
tower={
  init:function(){ console.log('horee im here now, finaly after a day code');}
}

// 3. app object
app ={ 
  publish:function(what,data){
     data.nextModule.init();
  }
}
// 2. then call this funct
var fires = function(){
   return app.publish('subscriber',{ nextModule : 'tower'});
}
// 1. execute this first
fires();
```

### Explanation Problem

- When i fire `fires()` 1.
- The 2. isfine  `app.publish('text',{nextModule:'tower');`
- Bypassed to 3. `app.publish(text,data)`

### My problem is

I want to convert `data.nextmodule` --> into an Object or Function
then call the tower module.init()

`data.nextModule.init()` cannot executed because `nextModule` is `String`

### how to make this code run like this

`data.'tower'.init();`

#### I have reading this reference

Answer by Houshalter
[converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) !not an String into an Object

Can **node js** to that?
Can we **covert to object** as easy as `JSON.stringify(data)` ?

### UPDATE ERROR on terminal

```
         throw err;
            ^
 TypeError: Object tower has no method `init`
```

Comment: Are you looking fro bracket notation? See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Node.js uses Chrome's V8 javascript engine which implements ECMAScript as specified in ECMA-262. So yes, if you can do it in the browser you can do it in Node.

Comment: its throw err `data["nextModule"].init();`
`typeError: Object tower has no method init..`

Answer (score 2):

Two things, first change the identifier `new` to something else.

Second,

`data.newxtModule` is a string that represents variable in your script. All variables are part of the `GLOBAL` object. So you can just retrieve that variable by passing that variable's name in string format to the GLOBAL object. And you will be able to call the `init()` of tower.

Simply change this line,

`data.nextModule.init();`

To,

`GLOBAL[data.nextModule].init();`

Final code should look like this.

```
// 4. execute tower.init latter read from bellow (1)
tower={
  init:function(){ console.log('horee im here now, finaly after a day code');}
}

// 3. app object
app ={ 
  publish:function(what,data){
     GLOBAL[data.nextModule].init();
  }
}
// 2. then call this funct
var new1 = function(){
   return app.publish('subscriber',{ nextModule : 'tower'});
}
// 1. execute this first
new1();
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iMaverick/o1rv5mdg/)

Comment: ofcourse my real code is not an `new` its `fire()` i will edit
but its still throw err has no method init..
js can do that why node canot..??

Comment: i try it on browser with js its works..
but it still has error on nodejs
what is GLOBAL[]? its kind of variable or array? 
can we convert thos string like we convert `JSON.stringify(data)`?
thanks..

Comment: You can think of GLOBAL in Node to be just like window in browser. It holds all the variables that are declared globally! Whether or not you can stringify GLOBAL object depends on presence of cyclic links within the object. If your GLOBAL object contains cycles (one property referencing to other property and so on) the JSON.stringify will throw error. GLOBAL is most likely to have cyclic properties.

Comment: also, your `data` is an object `stringify`ing it would stop data.nextModule from working. If you `stringify`the data paramenter, it will return you string and you won't be able to call nextModule on string :)

Answer (score 1):

Change 'tower' to tower.

By the way, you'd better do not use the key word 'new'.

Comment: i edit and try `fires()` its still object has no method..
how about fix by tryig `convert(data)` into data obj

Comment: but it works well if you update the string 'tower' without the quotation marks. here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nev0hhd/2/)