# Parse a URL into readable json format on a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

I would like to know how to parse this URL into readable JSON format with jQuery on a html page.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials online on how to do this. Please show what you have tried. SO isn't intended to just dump a bunch of data in and get code back. you are expected to do basic research yourself and when you have problems with live code post that

Comment: What URL? Please include all relevant information and code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to parse json into html, use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
$.getJSON( "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=a0b2a6ee7f4de028004b9ce7e4a29f42&format=json", function(data) {
    $("div").text(JSON.stringify(data))
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $.getJSON() function in jQuery. This writes the object in the console. It is human readable. And you can manipulate anyway you want with javascript.

```js
$.getJSON( "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=a0b2a6ee7f4de028004b9ce7e4a29f42&format=json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

```
var o = {a:1, b:2};
console.log(o);
console.log('Item: ' + o);
console.log('Item: ', o);
```

Output:

```
Object { a=1, b=2}           // useful
Item: [object Object]        // not useful
Item:  Object {a: 1, b: 2}   // Best of both worlds! :)
```

So what class was this homework assignment for?  What is your specific task?  Hint: we're going to let you get the data from the feed and store it into a javascript object variable, on your own...