# JS how to convert to string the Error Object from the window.error?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, onerror

I implemented:

```
 window.onerror = function (m, s, l, c, e) {
 }
```

Where the e is the Error Object. For example, it contains:

```
ReferenceError: rde is not defined
    at Object.bla.cs (domain.pt/bla.js:418:17)
    at n.aanv (domain.pt/bla.js:125:29)
```

If i make `e.toString()`, only the first line is returned. How to get the 3 lines? Thank you.

Comment: I also tried this: e.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") without success

Comment: `foreach(p in e){ console.log( e[p] ); }` or `JSON.stringify(e);` could help? Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string#answer-5612876).

Comment: It does not help. JSON.stringify(e) returns undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that the Error Object has a property called stack. so, e.stack is the full text of the error.

Comment: Error.stack is not part of spec. It's present in most browsers, but not edge, and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 20):

Error object have a `.message` property containing the full message (no need for `.toString()`. There is also `.stack` but it's not a standardized property.