# How to convert req.body to string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to save req.body to a string in node however whenever I do console.log(req.body.toString) the output is [object Object]. Any idea on what i could be doing wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/addUser', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.toString());
    res.end("thanks\n");
})
```

Output is:

`[object Object]`

When using JSON.stringify the output is:

```
" [object Object] "
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an object to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Comment: `req.body.outerHTML` perhaps?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your console.log(...) line. Then have a look at req.body.

Comment: console.log(req.body) itself prints out a json. I just want to save that as a string. @ThomCunningham

Comment: I very much doubt that JSON.stringify gives that output, unless you're doing `JSON.stringify(req.body.toString())`.

Comment: That's what I was doing @Juhana, thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert any JSON or js Object(non-circular) to string.
So in your case the following will work.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```

Comment: This is also handy because if you've missed and forgot to specify a property you'll know right away what one to use.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
JSON.stringify(req.body);
```

Object.prototype.toString will allways return a string with object + type, unless you override it.

Answer (score -1):

It is a circular object so u need to stringify it as follow:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

Comment: circular objects cant be stringified, i believe