# Node.js how to convert req.body to string

Tags: node.js, string, postman, tostring

I have tried these questions [Converting an object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) and [How to convert req.body to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211596/how-to-convert-req-body-to-string), but unfortunately they didn't solve my problem, I'm posting data using postman and I want to add a string  at specific location in received data. but when I tried to do so I either get [object Object] or {} instead of my original body content
**Here is my code**

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: '*' }));

app.post('/users', function (req, res, body) {
    var newData = `
    func addArtist(){
    //Anything
}
`;
    var body = req.body
    var abc = body.toString();
    var strlen = abc.length;
    var strlen = (strlen - 1);
    var txt2 = abc.slice(0, strlen) + newData + abc.slice(strlen);
    res.send(txt2);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**req.body is**

```
func anyName(){
    //Body of Function
}
```

**Output is:**

```
[object Object
    func addArtist(){
    //Anything
}]
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
func anyName(){
        //Body of Function
        func addArtist(){
        //Anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
    `JSON.stringify(req.body);`

Then this to convert back
    `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: I already did, it removes content of req.body and puts curly brackets

Comment: Not sure I understand.. So req.body is an object. And once you do stringify it removes the content of the body?

Comment: when i do console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); it shows only { }

Comment: JSON.stringify(req.body) and JSON.parse(req.body) both returns {}

Comment: Are you sure your req.body isn't just an empty object?  That's what this sounds like.

Comment: Try these settings                                                  
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

Comment: I'm pretty much sure @caden311