# javascript - how to get an object to return a value that is not the object itself

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When creating a `x = new Date()` object, if you put it into `console.log(x)` a string will be output.

Is there a way to make a custom object that will return a different value that is not an object itself

Comment: Not while using the `new` keyword. By definition, it will return an instance of the function you invoke. However, you can say something like `x = new MyObj().init()` and you can define an init function on your object that returns something other than the object itself.

Comment: Define the function `toString()` in your new object.

Comment: or use JSON.stringify like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) it even works with date-objects as well

Comment: @blauharley, mhodges i dont get the part that relates to the question.

Comment: @Jonasw I thought the OP wanted x to equal something that was not the object itself when saying `x = new Date()`. In all fairness, the question states "to make a custom object return a different value" and the title of the question states "get an object to return a value". The object is not returning a value when `console.log()` is called, the `toString()` function is returning a value. Technically my comment answers the actual question as it's worded, but I may have misunderstood the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically two methods returns values, which are not the object itself.

[`Object#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

> Every object has a `toString()` method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from `Object`. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, `toString() returns "[object type]", where *type* is the object type.

[`Object#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

> JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf` method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.
>
> By default, the `valueOf` method is inherited by every object descended from [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Every built-in core object overrides this method to return an appropriate value. If an object has no primitive value, `valueOf` returns the object itself.
>
> You can use valueOf within your own code to convert a built-in object into a primitive value. When you create a custom object, you can override `Object.prototype.valueOf()` to call a custom method instead of the default `Object` method.

To break it down for your question, you can implement both methods to a custom function.

When both methods are implemented and return primitive values, the `valueOf` is called first. If `valueOf` returns an object, `toString` method is called.

You might have a look to this article: [Fake operator overloading in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html)

```js
function Custom(value) {
    this.value = value;
}

Custom.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    console.log('valueOf');
    return this.value * 5;
};


var custom = new Custom(7);

console.log('' + custom); // no toString

Custom.prototype.toString = function () {
    console.log('toString');
    return this.value * 3;
};

Custom.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    console.log('valueOf');
    return {};
};

console.log('' + custom);
```

Comment: Is it possible to return an Array instead?

Comment: yes, you could return an array in `toString` method.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that, [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), however if you just do `console.log(new Test)` it will still output the object. But if your force it so print a string it will work: `console.log('%s', new Test)`:

```
function Test() {
}

Test.prototype.toString =
  function () {
    return "Something else";
  }


console.log("%s", new Test);

> Something else
```

Or if you concatenate it with another string:

```
var a = new Test;
console.log('Result: ' + a);

> Result: Something else
```

I use this a lot in my code to display a summary of the content of a object with data.

There is also [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
Test.prototype.valueOf =
  function () {
    return 42;
  }

console.log("%d", new Test);

> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Overwrite toString of an Object:**

My comment above refered to *toString* as well. You can use [*JSON.stringify*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to print out all properties of an object on the fly within an object's  toString method:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.a = 'a';
  this.b = 'b';
  this.c = 'c';
}

MyObject.prototype.toString = function () {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
};

console.log((new MyObject()).toString()); // {"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"}
// or
console.log('new MyObject(): ' + new MyObject()); // new MyObject(): {"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"}
```

**Overwrite console.log:**

Another try might be to overwrite console.log to print always strings (only tested in FF!):

```
// initialize this only once so that console.log prints out correctly

(function () {
  var oldConsole = console.log;
  console.log = function (obj) {
    oldConsole(JSON.stringify(obj));
  };
}) ();

// now console.log prints strings
console.log({
  a: 'a'
}); // String: {"a":"a"}

console.log(new Date()); // String: "2017-01-19T19:09:49.673Z"

console.log(document); // String: {"location":{"href":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748793/javascript-how-to-get-an-object-to-return-a-value-that-is-not-the-object-itsel/41749121#41749121","origin":"http://stackoverflow.com","protocol":"http:","host":"stackoverflow.com","hostname":"stackoverflow.com","port":"","pathname":"/questions/41748793/javascript-how-to-get-an-object-to-return-a-value-that-is-not-the-object-itsel/41749121","search":"","hash":"#41749121"},"jQuery112409140067213472354":3}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert most of the objects to string as follows

```
String(object)
```

like

```
x = String(new Date()); // now x is a string
```

Similarly

```
x = Boolean(0); // wil return an object
x = String(Boolean(0)); // will return a string
```

Comment: I dont see an answer