# convert object to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATED QUESTION**

here is my code :

```
function BillerDetails() {

var iState = _xmlCFHttp.readyState;
var sStatus = "";

if (iState == 4) {

    if (_xmlCFHttp.responseXML.xml != "") {
        var $accNum = $("#CXACNUM");
        var $accNme = $("#CXACNAM");
        _xmlCFRecv.loadXML(_xmlCFHttp.responseXML.xml);
        sStatus = _xmlCFRecv.selectSingleNode("/result/status").text;

        if (sStatus == "1") {

            if ($("#CXCLRCD option[value='" + $(this).children("Data1").text() + "']").length == 0) {

                $("#CXACNUM").val($("#CXACNUM").val("Data5"));
                $("#CXACNAM").val($("#CXACNAM").val("Data4"));    
            }


        } else {
            var msg = _xmlCFRecv.selectSingleNode("/result/message").text;

            if (msg != "") {
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Data4 and Data5 is a field inside the database. these need to be display in the textbox. however as previous, it return output at the textbox as below :

```
Object Object
```

Comment: You should look into `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Comment: What's the point of nested `.val()` functions?

Comment: @31piy that is what is causing this issue val() returns jquery object when setting a value

Answer (score 3):

> However when it display, it give me output :
>
> [Object object]

This is because you are setting the returned value of [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) back to the same input, **which is a jquery object**

You need to simply do

```
$("#CXACNUM").val( JSON.stringify( Data5 ) );
```

Comment: hi, i tried using stringify. however, it still give me the same result.

Comment: @Izzy can you share what `Data5` looks like? If possible, create a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: Data5 by right supposedly a number, for example "75412985". it is from database.

Comment: Can you share the output of `console.log( JSON.stringify( Data5 ) )` ?

Comment: i already update the question. my full javascript code. if you dont mind, please help me check.

Comment: even we use JSON.stringify in [Object,Object] it will just convert it into its string format "[Object,Object]"

Answer (score 1):

Try using `JSON.stringify` as

```
$("#CXACNUM").val(JSON.sringify(Data5));
```

Comment: Hi I can delete the answer but by the time i was typing the answer there was no answer yet, check the timestamps its almost same, you dont ned to down vote for it, just ask to remove :(

Comment: hi, i tried using stringify. however, it still give me the same result.

Answer (score -1):

```
      function BillerDetails() {

        var iState = _xmlCFHttp.readyState;
       var sStatus = "";

    if (iState == 4) {

          if (_xmlCFHttp.responseXML.xml != "") {
             var $accNum = $("#CXACNUM");
             var $accNme = $("#CXACNAM");
            _xmlCFRecv.loadXML(_xmlCFHttp.responseXML.xml);
            sStatus = _xmlCFRecv.selectSingleNode("/result/status").text;

         if (sStatus == "1") {

           if ($("#CXCLRCD option[value='" + $(this).children("Data1").text() + "']").length == 0) {
            var Data4Val=$(this).children("Data4").text();
            var Data5Val=$(this).children("Data5").text();
            $("#CXACNUM").val($("#CXACNUM").val(Data5Val));
            $("#CXACNAM").val($("#CXACNAM").val(Data4Val));    
        }


          } else {
                var msg = _xmlCFRecv.selectSingleNode("/result/message").text;

           if (msg != "") {
               alert(msg);
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

i have updated your code. hope this will work

Comment: can you send attach a response xml. or share it in fiddle

Comment: print $(this) in a console and put the output here. so we can identify how to parse your XML data to fetch your required data.