# How to check (expect) if object / array contains particular string in Protractor?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I wrote following condition in Protractor test:

```
expect(dialog.getAttribute('style')).toContain('display: none');
```

That raises an error:

```
Expected [ 'display: none; width: 400px;' ] to contain 'display: none'.
```

So, I've tried to add a call to `.toString()` method after getAttribute, but it returns `[object Object]'. The error is as follows:

```
Expected '[object Object]' to contain 'display: none'.
```

I've tried answers posted here: [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) but they seems to not work
but they're also not working.

How should I amend my code, so that test will pass?

Comment: Show the definition of variable `dialog`

Comment: `const dialog = element(by.css('p-dialog[header="Deleting"]'));`

Since te suggested solution for this issue was to use `element` instead of `all`, I wonder if I should delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare the variable `dialog` as an element list, like `element.all()`, so `getAttribute()` will return a list.

Please clarify you hope `dialog` be a single element or an element list.

Comment: In my case, I provide such locator, that only one element should be returned. I've tried to add a call to get method (`.get(0)`), but it returned me an error. Should I use `first` or `last` instead to obtain one element only?

Comment: pleas show the code how you declare/init the variable `dialog`.