# Mongo find() returns [object Object] in express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

so basically i'm trying to access Pages collection from header.ejs

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.pages= Pages.find();
    next();
});
```

but when i try to access it from the html it display [object object]

and when i display it on console.log it shows a lot

```
createIndexes instead.
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts: 
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'pages',
     collectionName: 'pages',
     conn: ....................
```

how can i access from html by array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`Pages.find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) by default will return a cursor. You'll want to use a [callback](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm) to handle what you've found:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  Pages.find({}, (err, pages) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.locales.pages = pages;
    return next();
  });
});
```

2. Check out 
   [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) for info on how to convert an object or array to a `string`. By default, when you convert an object to a string, it will read `[object Object]` (you can verify this by doing `const a = {}; console.log({}.toString())`)

Comment: You can always get a few points most every day answering a question just like this!