# Obtaining details for airbrake-js error objects

Tags: vue.js, airbrake, errbit

I use Errbit and airbrake-js

Errbit
https://github.com/errbit/errbit

My Vue js errors are reported by airbrake-js to Errbit with airbrake-js.

```
airbrake.notify({
    error: err,
    params: {
      info: info
    }
```

vue errors are reported to errbit.

but MESSAGE of Errbit is like 100.0%  [object Object].

How can I get details about the Object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Comment: In order to help troubleshoot, I'd like to see a bit more info. From Chrome, can you trigger one of these errors and capture information from the network panel? If you can right click the network request to errbit and select `Copy as curl` and paste the result into your question, I think that will help narrow down the culprit. Be sure to scrub out any info you don't want the world to see. The payload will be the most interesting part for debugging.