# can we print array outside the loop i javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    </div>
    <script>
        let list = [];
        let ob={};
        for(i=0; i<100; i++){
            list[i] = {
                name: i,
                text: "text"
            }  
            //document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += list[i].name + list[i].text + '<br/>'
        }
        console.log(list)
        var lising = document.getElementById('results');
        
        lising.innerHTML = list
        </script>
</body>
```

in above code i can print the array inside the loop but when i try to print it outside, it prints [object object]

Comment: maybe list.join()?

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(list)```

Comment: list.map(x => x.name + x.text).join("<br />")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Comment: nopes. converting an array into the string prints the data in json format. i want plain text next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to put `string` value to `innerHTML` and now, you put `Array` object value in `innerHTML` attribute.
Converting the `list` array to string and assign will work.

```
let list = [];
let ob = {};
for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
  list[i] = {
    name: i,
    text: 'text'
  };
}
console.log(list);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list.map(({name, text}) => `${name} ${text}`).join("<br/>");
```

Comment: hey thanks. but converting an array into the string prints the data in json format. i want plain text next to each other

Comment: @cshendye Now, the answer is updated. Pls check, it's fully customizable.

Comment: Perfect. thanks. btw cant we print the array as it is? without again looping through or converting to strings? just for my knowledge

Comment: You can make a javascript function which performs that action and call that function to convert the `list`.

Comment: didn't get you.

Comment: So innerHTML only accepts string value so you are not able to put array object directly.

Comment: ok, so instead of innerHTML can we use any other method?

Comment: To update html element using javascript, only `innerHTML` and `innerText` are available. No other ways except them.