# Transfer data from nodejs to html using socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to transfert data from nodejs to html using socket.io.
First I tried to transfert text from nodejs to html and it works :

nodejs code :

```
app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    io.emit('messageFromServer', "text");
});
```

html code :

```
<ul id="messagesList">
                    
</ul>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
            var socket = io();
            var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
            socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');        
            item.innerHTML = data;
            list.appendChild(item);
            });
            </script>
```

Text appears between    ul id="messagesList"  AND  /ul  .

Now I want to transfer variable from nodejs to html. The variable is emit from python and it works. But I can't write this variable into the html page and I don't know why.

Nodejs code : info is the variable from python.

```
app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    var info = req.body;
    io.emit('messageFromServer', info);
    console.log(info)
});
```

When I launch the python code, the console.log(info) write : { time: '10' }

html code (the same):

```
            <ul id="messagesList">
            
            </ul>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
                var socket = io();
                var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
                
                socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
                var item = document.createElement('li');        
                item.innerHTML = data;
                list.appendChild(item);

                });
            </script>
```

When I launch the python code, the html write :  [objet, Object], but I want : " time 10 ".
How can I adapt my code ?
Thanks.

===============================

Now it works with these codes :
Nodejs :

```
app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    var info = req.body;
    io.emit('messageFromServer', info);
    console.log(info)
});
```

and html :

```
            <ul id="messagesList">
            
            </ul>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
                var socket = io();
                var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
                socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
                var item = document.createElement('li'); 
                item.innerHTML = data.time;
                list.appendChild(item);
                });
            </script>
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: change `item.innerHTML = data` to `item.innerHTML = "time " + data.time`. You are assigning an object to the DOM where you need to assign a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe solve your problem.

```
item.innerHTML = data.time
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I tested with data.time, my html page writes " undefined"...