# Can I execute a function in response to a failed assert in TestCafe?

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are using Testcafe for our regression tests and I would like to enhance the test logging of failed asserts by adding any messages from the browser console to the output. According to the Testcafe documentation, this code will print "**The test has failed**" in case the given element is not visible on the page:

```
await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').visible).ok("The test has failed");
```

According to the doco, the browser console messages can be read using the the t.getBrowserConsoleMessages method, but I have not been able to combine them into one statement like e.g.

```
await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').visible).ok(console.log(await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages()));
```

as this always processes the getBrowserConsoleMessages method and outputs the console messages, regardless of whether the assert is successful or not.

Is there a way to make this work only if the assert fails?

Comment: Update: I think I found an answer. The approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I seems you just need to call getBrowserConsoleMessages conditionally.
To get the expected behavior, you can use the following code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`A set of examples that illustrate how to use TestCafe API`
    .page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;

test('Test1', async t => {
    
    const isVisible = await Selector('#developer-name').visible;
    if (!isVisible)
        console.log(await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages())
    await t.expect(isVisible).ok();
});

test('Test2', async t => {
    
    const isVisible = await Selector('#developer-name2').visible;
    if (!isVisible)
        console.log(await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages())
    await t.expect(isVisible).ok();
});
```

Comment: That might work but it looks like it may blow up the code in case of a large number of asserts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this working myself:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

async function objToString (obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((str, [p, val]) => {
      return `${str}${p}::${val}\n`;
  }, '');
}

fixture('My test')
  .page('https://myurl.com')

test('Test1', async t => {
    ....
    await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').visible).ok(await objToString(await browser.getBrowserConsoleMessages()));
    ....
});
```