# Javascript How to print an object using string interpolation

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, string-interpolation

is there any way to print the object using string interpolation method?

```
const star = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Arcturus',
    visualMag: -0.05,
};
```

This method doesnt work

```
console.log(`${star}`); // [object Object]
```

This works

```
console.log(`${star.name}`); // 'Arcturus'
```

and simply using console.log(star) works

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(star))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

When you use an object within template literal, it coerces the object to a string.  It looks for a `toString` method on the object. If it is not found, it will use `Object.prototype.toString` method which returns `"[object Object]"`.

So, add a `toString` property to the object.

```js
const star = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Arcturus',
  visualMag: -0.05,
};

Object.defineProperty(star, "toString", {
  value: function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this)
  }
})

console.log(`${star}`);
```

Note: You could directly add `star.toString = function() { ... }`. But, that will add an enumerable property to the object and will be displayed when you log the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify

```
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(test)}`)
```

Comment: Note that the template string is useless here. Use instead `console.log(JSON.stringify(test));`

Answer (score -1):

Hey do this simple trick:

```
console.log({star});
```

Output:

```
[Log] {star: {id: 1, name: "Arcturus", visualMag: -0.05}}
```

Comment: You are missing the "_using string interpolation_" part.

Comment: This is not string interpolation.