# ECMAScript5 deep copy of object and arrays

Tags: javascript, associative-array, deep-copy, ecmascript-5, object-object-mapping

I'd hope to find an example code to do a deep copying of objects in ECMAScript5.

The copying should be able to clone

- Nested objects
- Nested arrays
- Nested objects in arrays (clone each array item individually)

Note: jQuery.extend() does not seem to handle case 3). Also, I'd hope to do this in clean ECMAScript. Quick googling did not bring up any worthy implementations.

Comment: Deep copying is a non trivial problem, I recommend you change your algorithm so it works with a shallow copy

Comment: Currently I am doing it with jQuery.extend() and manually cleaning up the mess afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally settled to `jQuery.extend()` as I couldn't find other good implementations

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 1):

if you want a one-liner (removes object refs by iterating through referenced objects to retrieve primitives, concats one large string, then parses the string into a new object with it's own primitive leaf nodes)

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

or if you need to perform many copies

```
function deepCopy(o) {
    var copy = o,k;

    if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        copy = Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]' ? [] : {};
        for (k in o) {
            copy[k] = deepCopy(o[k]);
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

[performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-json-stringify-json-parse)

Comment: What do you mean? This does perform a deep copy. Its not specifically ECMAScript5 but neither is jQuery right?

Comment: Sorry! What I meant to say is please explain what's the code doing?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer) of the [toSource method](http://www.webreference.com/javascript/reference/core_ref/object.html#1193320) to copy the object:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Object.prototype.getSource = function() {
      var output = [], temp;
      for (var i in this) {
          if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
              temp = i + ":";
              switch (typeof this[i]) {
                  case "object" :
                      temp += this[i].getSource();
                      break;
                  case "string" :
                      temp += "\"" + this[i] + "\"";    // add in some code to escape quotes
                      break;
                  default :
                      temp += this[i];
              }
              output.push(temp);
          }
      }
      return "{" + output.join() + "}";
      }
      var baz = {"alpha":{"beta":{"charlie": ["delta","epsilon",{"omega":"zeta"}]}}};
      !!Object.prototype.toSource ? alert((baz).toSource() ) : alert((baz).getSource() );
    </script>
```

Comment: A start, but isn't this little fragile.. possible infinite loop with cyclic references?

Comment: [Contact the developer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf) of this solution for help with robustness.