# Can a jQuery plug-in be local to a module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, module-pattern

I really like the JavaScript module pattern to encapsulate data and logic. I'm also using jQuery extensively. My question is this:

If I define a jQuery extension/plug-in WITHIN a module, will it be local to that module like other functions would be? (I suspect the answer is no...)

Example:

```
var igPartListManager = (function () {
    // Define a jQuery plug-in I'd like to be local to igPartListManager 
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myExtension = function () {
            // Do something with this.each()...
        }
    })(jQuery);

    var doSomethingCore = function () {
        // Use my jQuery plug-in
        $("selector").myExtension();
    };

    return {
        doSomething
            : doSomethingCore
    };
})();
```

Outside of igPartListManager, would this succeed?

```
...
$("some_unrelated_selector").myExtension();
```

If it does, how do I best encapsulate 'local' jQuery-extension/plug-in-like functionality within a module?

Comment: variables are local to scope, not modules, but in this case the jQuery plugin is a function, and a function creates a new scope, so yes! However, $ is a global, so when using the right quotes in the selector, the plugin works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better explain this I made a little example of what actually happens when you define your extension:

```
(function ($) {
    // $ = window.jQuery;
    $.fn.myExtension = function () {
        // Do something with this.each()...
    }
})(window.jQuery); // Note window.jQuery is basically the same as just jQuery from your example code
```

Whenever you try to access a variable, the javascript engine bubbles up trough all encapsulating scopes all the way up to the `window` scope. The first scope that has that variable is the scope that is being used. Since in your case the window scope holds your `jQuery` variable you could call it 'global'.

When calling this `$("some_unrelated_selector).myExtension();` the engine looks for the variable `$`. If this variable points to `window.jQuery` at that point, you are in fact using the same object as before. So yes, that would succeed in that case. But only if you executed the `igPartListManager` function before trying to call `$().myExtension();`.

The only way to create a local scope for your extensions is to deep copy the `window.jQuery` variable to a local variable before adding extensions to it.

Example:
[Javascript deep copying object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299284/javascript-deep-copying-object)

Comment: Thank you @Hless. I am re-thinking my requirements here because I am not sure I'll be using the jQuery extension enough within my module to justify my own 'deep copy' of jQuery. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, I think adding functions to `$.fn` of the global object is your best bet at this point. The jQuery class does get heavier, but I don't think having a complete copy of that class does you any good, performance wise. It's practically the same as loading the jQuery source code multiple times, using different variable names each time.

Comment: And yet the functions I want are LOCAL to my module, so adding them to the global $.fn is leakage I don't want. No one else will want these functions.