# Deep cloning/copy for javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, clone

Looking for ways to deep copy objects that contain nested and circular structures, neither of these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299284/javascript-deep-copying-object), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)) had the perfect solution when it comes to circular references and prototypal inheritance.

I've written my own [implementation](https://github.com/yazjisuhail/js/blob/master/implementations/deepClone.js) here. Does it do the job well or count as a better solution?

```
 /*
    a function for deep cloning objects that contains other nested objects and circular structures.
    objects are stored in a 3D array, according to their length (number of properties) and their depth in the original object.
                                    index (z)
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |                      depth (x)
                                         |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                                        /_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/
                                       /_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/
                                      /_/_/_/_/_/_/...../
                                     /................./
                                    /.....            /
                                   /                 /
                                  /------------------
            object length (y)    /
*/


function deepClone(obj) {
    var i = -1, //depth of the current object relative to the passed 'obj'
        j = 0;  //number of the object's properties
    var arr = new Array(); //3D array to store the references to objects
    return clone(obj, arr, i, j);
}

function clone(obj, arr, i ,j){
    if (typeof obj !== "object") {
        return obj;
    }

    var result = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); //inherit the prototype of the original object
    if(result instanceof Array){
        result.length = Object.keys(obj).length;
    }

    i++; //depth is increased because we entered an object here
    j = Object.keys(obj).length; //native method to get the number of properties in 'obj'
    arr[i] = new Array(); //this is the x-axis, each index here is the depth
    arr[i][j] = new Array(); //this is the y-axis, each index is the length of the object (aka number of props)
    //start the depth at current and go down, cyclic structures won't form on depths more than the current one
    for(var depth = i; depth >= 0; depth--){
        //loop only if the array at this depth and length already have elements
        if(arr[depth][j]){
            for(var index = 0; index < arr[depth][j].length; index++){
                if(obj === arr[depth][j][index]){
                    return obj;
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    arr[i][j].push(obj); //store the object in the array at the current depth and length
    for (var prop in obj) {
        result[prop] = clone(obj[prop], arr, i, j);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)?

Comment: @Ja͢ck had a glance at that before. I believe it doesn't deal with circular structures, right?

Comment: plus, you need to manually implement the special cases (e.g. Date, Array, etc.)

Comment: Right in the first paragraph the page that describes the structured clone algorithm mentions cyclic graphs. Basically this problem is the well studied graph traversal problem.

Comment: @akonsu I was reading through its pseudo [implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data). Which one you think would be faster? 3D array, as I approached it, or a map, as they approached?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below simple logic. Convert js object into new String and again convert as object.

E.g:

```
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
var cloneStr = new String(JSON.stringify(car));
var carClone = JSON.parse(cloneStr);
carClone.type = "Maruthi";
alert(JSON.stringify(car)) ;
alert(JSON.stringify(carClone)) ;
```