# how to loop through the Restfulwebservice using for loop with a object

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

How to loop through the Restfulwebserivice using for loop with a single object. and I don't want to use for each loop so how do i do this. i am not able to get the data by using

```
  for(var key in data) {
                    alert(data[key].hotel_geo_node.name);
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           }
```

and here is the api 
    {
      "data": {
        "4325474491990470056": {
            "hotel_geo_node": {
                "name": "The Capitol", 
                "tags": {
                    "hotel_chain_code": [
                        "nichendgrp"
                    ], 
                    "property_type": [
                        "Hotel"
                    ], 
                    "property_budget_category": [
                        "Luxury"
                    ], 
                    "others": [
                        "goibibo_hotel"
                    ]
                },

```
    }, 

   "4325474491990470057": {
        "hotel_geo_node": {
            "name": "The Capitol", 
            "tags": {
                "hotel_chain_code": [
                    "nichendgrp"
                ], 
                "property_type": [
                    "Hotel"
                ], 
                "property_budget_category": [
                    "Luxury"
                ], 
                "others": [
                    "goibibo_hotel"
                ]
            }, 

    }, 
    "4325474491990470058": {
        "hotel_geo_node": {
            "name": "The Capitol", 
            "tags": {
                "hotel_chain_code": [
                    "nichendgrp"
                ], 
                "property_type": [
                    "Hotel"
                ], 
                "property_budget_category": [
                    "Luxury"
                ], 
                "others": [
                    "goibibo_hotel"
                ]
            }, 
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop through object's keys using "standard" `for` loop since it is not array and it's keys are not numbers. You can only loop throw it using `for-in` loop:

```
for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){ // check if 'key' property is in object 'data' and not in it's prototype chain
        doTheStuff(data[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi roland, i need get every object just like we get every array and loop through that array i want the same thing. how do i do that . :(

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what do you want. If you want to rich that objects named like `"4325474491990470058", you'll get it in the line 3 of my snippet as `data[key]`. Or if you wanna get all nested objects you can do it using recursion function similar to that one in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11311206/1105860

Comment: okay!! so how do i get "name": "The Capitol" from this web service. please let me know.

Comment: since it's looks like API you can just get `data[key].hotel_geo_node.name`

Comment: Hi Roland, I am getting this error TypeError: data[key].hotel_geo_node is undefined .

Comment: Hey, bro, who's programming that stuff - you or me? ;-)

Comment: programing is doing by me but i tried all the things but couldn't get the name from all object . don't know why i am getting this error .

Comment: use chrome dev.tools, go to debugger, turn on 'stop on exceptions', check variables, check your object. Investigate.