# JavaScript (JS) function array equality works as pointer? How to just use the variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was creating a code where I need to use some variables from a global scope, when I made my local = global, I've noticed the changes I've made in the local scope were being modified into the global scope.

This is an example of what I am talking about

```
global = [];
load_global();
use_global();

function load_global() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    global.push(i);
  }
}

function use_global() {
  local = [];
  local = global;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    global.push("x");
  }
  console.log(local);
}
```

[JSbin Example](http://jsbin.com/kesuharevo/edit?js,console)

Is there a way to use the values of a global array, but without changing it?

Comment: `local` is in the global scope too, you really really need to be careful with those variables (always use the `var` keyword, or `window`) to ensure it is where you expect them to be

Comment: It is not an equality. Equality is  `==` or `===`. `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: I have so many good explanations here and great help, that I don't know how to say, this one is the best, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides old school `Array#slice`, you can use the ES6 method `Array.from`, which is designed for such scenarios:

```
var local = Array.from(global)
```

This method can be used on array-like objects or any iterable values, which don't have a `slice` method. You may say `Array.prototype.slice.call()`. Oops you are right, but isn't that annoying?

Besides, you can pass a mapping function to it as well. For example:

```
Array.from('asdf', c => c.toUpperCase())  // ["A", "S", "D", "F"]
```

Comparing to ES5 style, you can see how neat ES6 is:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call('asdf').map(function(c){return c.toUpperCase()})
```

Read [**MDN doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for more.

On the other hand, the method is not widely supported at the moment, you need babel or a polyfill. But ES6 is the future, eventually it'll be fully supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Is there any advantage to use this method?

Comment: @VanHalenBR I updated the answer regarding your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try copying the global array

```
local = global.slice()
```

btw you might wanna use `var` keyword to make that array local. Without it the "local" array will be accessible from outside of the function

Comment: Thanks I was trying to use push but was creating a array inside an array

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the array into a local variable. You can do that with `slice` or `concat` for example.

To add `clone` to javascript arrays, you can use

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    return this.slice(0);
};
```

And then

```
var localArray = globalArray.clone();
```

Also check this SO question here [Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

Comment: I'm quite uneasy with prototyping native `Array`, and even if you do so, it is more likely to be named `cloneShallow`

Comment: Its up to your preference, just using slice is probably more easy yes.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, as in many other languages, you only handle references of objects. This also means that the object "inside" your array could also need to be copied. The answers based on the use of `Array.slice()` are excellent but it doesn't make a *[deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy)* of the items in the array (meaning the Object element in the array are also copied so changing the state of a local object doesnt affect your global object).

One very simple (but maybe not very efficient) solution could be to serialize and deserialize your array. Ex:

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Note that using JSON doesn't allow you to handle an functions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) was an answer using this technique.

**EDIT**

To allow deep copy, you can also iterate the properties of the object as DMaster suggested but you should use some kine of recursion. I have taken this example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299284/javascript-deep-copying-object) in SO.

```
function clone(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
        if (typeof source[property] === "object" && source[property] !== null && destination[property]) { 
            clone(destination[property], source[property]);
        } else {
            destination[property] = source[property];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up  to you, @DMaster but this solution is currently the only one to make a deep copy of the array which could appear to be required later.

Comment: I have another solution that also copy functions: using `forEach`, with an array, simply `array.forEach(copier)`, with an object, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).forEach(copier)`.
Feel free to add it in your answer if you want.

Comment: @DMaster Thank you. I will certainly rework my answer when I have time. Your solution is cleaner but it requires more implementation effort (either specific copiers or generic ones implying recursive calls) and thus more time.

Comment: there're differeces between `for...in` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, I think you should mention both of them, or I will edit your post, shouldn't I?