# Passing on a function from server to client

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, paradigms

I recently ran into the foo.toSource() option in JavaScript. This allows a serialization of a function.
I was wondering about the possibilities of transferring functions over the networks, from server to client, and executing them at a later time - with eval().

Do you think it's actually useful?
Are there any frameworks using such a paradigm?

Comment: 1) `toSource()` is IE-only, see answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer) for implementations in other browsers. 2) what is the connection of `toSource` to the questions you are asking?

Comment: I suggest you don't use eval(); it is slow and if code is user-generated you risk XSS.

Comment: Thanks. My question is more theoretic.. I didn't mean to suggest the actual why of doing it (the toSource is just a possible way to serialize a function to be transferred over the network).

Answer (score 0):

Passing functions from the server to a page can be done without toSource, by just putting it in the code when the page is generated on the server, or requesting it via AJAX when needed.

Comment: Thanks! yes, I thought about what you are saying, and that leads me to my next question/wonder: is it possible to transfer a function with it's closure? Do you think that kind of feature will be useful?

Answer (score 0):

The only use cases I see are:

1. whenever you send .js file
2. [JSNOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

The thing you thought about isn't posible. So we can only send the text representation of the function, not it's context or closures and all that stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks! that was helpful. I guess I didn't think this through.