# jQuery - FormData() append not working?

Tags: jquery, input, fileinputstream

I have this simple snippet in which I wnat to add a selected file from a inputfield in FormData-Object, but whatever I do, a `data.toSource()` always returns nothing.

Can someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/ktcjjff4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#basicUploadFile').live('change', function () {        

    data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)  {
        data.append('userfile', this.files[i].name);
        alert(this.files[i].name);
    }

    alert(data.toSource());       


    });    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data.toSource()` is **not a function** in Chrome or Safari. It should have been:

```
data.toString();  // OR
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Also `toSource()` does not work in Internet Explorer or Safari. It is Gecko-only. See [Implementing Mozilla's toSource() method in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer) for alternatives.

Comment: I only did the `toSource()` to see if the file from my input has been put into the FormData

Comment: @user5517285 Try `FormData.entries()` also.

Comment: @user5517285 Chrome support for methods other than append is currently behind the "Enable Experimental Web Platform Features" flag.

Comment: @user5517285 See more information in [`FormData` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).