# JavaScript Function.prototype.toSource() in Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a problem with the script below. I'm getting `toSource` is not defined error in Chrome and found out that [`toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource) is Firefox specific. I tried `JSON.stringify()` instead, for which I got undefined error.

```
var main_tbls = d.querySelectorAll(".bz_buglist");
var first_tbl = main_tbls[0];
first_tbl.id = "bugz_table";
var ext_script = d.createElement("script");
//ext_script.setAttribute("src", "http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tablefilter.js");
ext_script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
ext_script.setAttribute("language", "javascript");
ext_script.appendChild(d.createTextNode("var TblId, SearchFlt, SlcArgs;TblId = new Array(), SlcArgs = new Array();var colValues = new Array();" +
    setFilterGrid.toSource() +
    AddGrid.toSource() ));
d.body.appendChild(ext_script);


function setFilterGrid(id)
{
    var tbl = grabEBI(id);
    var ref_row, fObj;
    if (tbl != null && tbl.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "table") {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var argtype = typeof arguments[i];

                switch (argtype.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "number":
                        ref_row = arguments[i];
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        fObj = arguments[i];
                        break;
                } //switch

            } //for
        } //if

        ref_row == undefined ? ref_row = 2 : ref_row = (ref_row + 2);
        var ncells = getCellsNb(id, ref_row);
        tbl.tf_ncells = ncells;
        if (tbl.tf_ref_row == undefined) tbl.tf_ref_row = ref_row;
        tbl.tf_Obj = fObj;
        if (!hasGrid(id)) AddGrid(id);
    } //if tbl!=null
}
```

Comment: there is no inner function `toSource` defined inside `seFilterGrid`

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What is your goal? What end result do you want? What specifically about the output of `JSON.stringify` was problematic?

Comment: @user2181397 : toSource is an inbuilt firefox plugin ! I want to use the chrome equivalent of it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171407/implementing-mozillas-tosource-method-in-internet-explorer

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's a non-standard prototype only implemented in Gecko, that you generally shouldn't use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your question is not clear, it appears that you are looking for the **[`Function.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)** method. This will work in [basically all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString#Browser_compatibility).

```js
document.body.innerHTML =  '<pre>' + setFilterGrid.toString() +'</pre>';


function setFilterGrid(id)
{
    var tbl = grabEBI(id);
    var ref_row, fObj;
    if (tbl != null && tbl.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "table") {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                var argtype = typeof arguments[i];

                switch (argtype.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "number":
                        ref_row = arguments[i];
                        break;
                    case "object":
                        fObj = arguments[i];
                        break;
                } //switch

            } //for
        } //if

        ref_row == undefined ? ref_row = 2 : ref_row = (ref_row + 2);
        var ncells = getCellsNb(id, ref_row);
        tbl.tf_ncells = ncells;
        if (tbl.tf_ref_row == undefined) tbl.tf_ref_row = ref_row;
        tbl.tf_Obj = fObj;
        if (!hasGrid(id)) AddGrid(id);
    } //if tbl!=null
}
```

**[`Function.prototype.toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource)**, on the other hand,  is [only available in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource#Browser_compatibility). Mozilla's documentation is quite clear that it is:

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks Man Worked :)