# jQuery datepicker setting date not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

The developer tools show no error message. Works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
console.log($("#datepicker").datepicker("isDisabled")); // prints false
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
console.log("here"); // doesn't print at all
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  The jQuery UI datepicker definitely works in IE8.

Comment: I just edited the question, it's much simpler now. To answer your question, i just have `<input id="datepicker" type="hidden"/>`. Also, some setup is clearly happening, since I can see the DOM additions made by datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize IE8 even supported the console object. From what [I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8), it looks like you need to turn on Developer Tools (F12) to get it to work. Otherwise, console might be causing a JavaScript error which is killing your date picker logic. And make sure you're [not using Firebug Lite in IE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8/1596931#1596931)

Comment: -1 The 2nd line prints to console (according to the comment on the source), so I guess IE8 does support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryDate = '2009-11-06',
dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g);
realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' }); // format to show
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
```

this code will help you..