# Get all attributes of an object - not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010, attributes

In the following code, I included an attribute for debugging.  In FF and Chrome, I get a ton of alerts saying "attribute found", but in IE, I get nothing.  The function returns an empty array.

I have also tried removing the `console.info(this)` line.

BTW, I'm using SPServices to access lists from SharePoint 2010 -- I'm trying to get all the columns of a list.

```
/*!
 * listAttributes jQuery Plugin v1.1.0
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Michael Riddle
 * Licensed under the MIT
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: Sun Mar 28 05:49:39 2010 -0900
 */

 //THIS ISN'T WORKING IN IE
if(jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function(prefix) {
            var list = [];
            var attributes = [];
            $(this).each(function() {
                console.info(this);
                for(var key in this.attributes) {
                alert("attribute found");
                    if(!isNaN(key)) {
                        if(!prefix || this.attributes[key].name.substr(0,prefix.length) == prefix) {
                            attributes.push(this.attributes[key].name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.push(attributes);
            });
            return attributes;
        }
    });
}
//end listAttributes Plugin - use this to see what attributes 


function ImportSPListColumnsToArray(ListName)
{
    var ArrayForStorage = new Array();
$(document).ready(function() {


  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: ListName,
    CAMLViewFields: "",
    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/></QueryOptions>",
    **completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
      //find all fields used by each row and aggregate them without duplicating
      var row_attr = $(this).listAttributes();**
      for (var i=0; i<row_attr.length; i++)
        {
            if ($.inArray(ArrayForStorage, row_attr[i]) == -1)
                {
                    ArrayForStorage.push(row_attr[i]);
                }
        }
      row_attr.clear();
      });
    }
  });

});
  return ArrayForStorage;

}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but just FYI: it's unusual to declare a plugin inside `$(document).ready()`. It's more common to declare it in the global scope. Also when you're using `$(this).each`... `this` will already be a jQuery object, so you can (and should) be using just `this.each`

Comment: What is `.listAttributes();`? I don't think it's part of the jQuery library. [EDIT] Oops, sorry, I was only seeing part of your code.

Comment: @bfavaretto that's why Christian has `jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function(prefix) { ... }`

Comment: @Matt - `this` is the DOM element. For example `this.hide()` will not work only `$(this).hide()` will - **Examples** `this`: http://jsfiddle.net/9yxe8/ `$(this)` http://jsfiddle.net/4a6fE/ ------- What is good practice is to cache `$(this)` ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Bjhbc/

Comment: @Peter: In the case where he's using `$(this).each`, `this` is pointing to the `jQuery` object he called `listAttributes` on: http://jsfiddle.net/Bjhbc/1/

Comment: @Matt: taking out the $(document).ready and changing $(this) to this did not resolve the issue.  That's good insight, though.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

IE apparently doesn't recognize `this.attributes` as having a length in the for each loop.

So I just iterated through them, and it worked.

```
if(jQuery) {
        jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function() {
            var attributes = new Array();
            $(this).each(function() {
                for (var i=0; i<this.attributes.length; i++)
                {
                    attributes.push(this.attributes.item(i).nodeName);
                }
            });
            return attributes;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe your problem is the `console.info(this);` line. IE does not have this available out of the box ([you need to open Developer Tools first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)), so you're script is failing at that point.

Comment: I have developer tools open and have also tried removing that line.  No change...