# how to rectify this error in ie 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery autosuggest to populate the data in a text box. When i am trying to work that functionality in ie8 i am getting the error: console not define

The jquery code where it is showing error is :

```
function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            // post data to our php processing page and if there is a return greater than zero
            // show the suggestions box
            $.post("string_search.php", {mysearchString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){

                **console.log(data.length)**
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }else{
                $('#suggestions').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    } //end
```

Please help me in solving the error

Comment: This post has an answer and a fallback strategy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: @voigtan it doesn't?!  Wow, the reasons not to use IE just continue to mount up...

Comment: press F12 to open the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, the console exists in IE too. However `console` is not defined until after opening the Developer Tools (press F12). So unless the Developer Tools are already open when the page is loaded, then it will fail.

One solution is to add something like the following to the top of your file (i.e. before you use console):

```
<script>
    try {
        console.log('Hello console!');
    } catch(e) {
        console = {log: function(){}};
    }
</script>
```

This ensures that `console.log` is always available, even if it is a no-op.

Comment: Thank you very much for all my friends who helped me to get out of that error and now i am working fine with it. Thanks a lot to stackoverflow for this wonderful application which helps lot of guys like me

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.console && window.console.log)
     console.log(data.length)
else
    alert(data.length);
```