# Jquery class is not responding to .click() despite being listed within selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some several labels on a webpage, that can be clicked, and all share the class 'btn'.  In the console, if I use the selector `$('.btn');` among others the following elements DO appear:

```
<label id=​"skillstable_Certification" class=​"row btn">​Certification​</label>​,
<label id=​"skillstable_Compliance" class=​"row btn">​Compliance​</label>​,
<label id=​"skillstable_Technology" class=​"row btn">​Technology​</label>​,
<label id=​"skillstable_version(s)​" class=​"column btn">​Version(s)​</label>,​
<label id=​"skillstable_startdate" class=​"column btn">​StartDate​</label>​,
<label id=​"skillstable_enddate" class=​"column btn">​EndDate​</label>​,
<label id=​"skillstable_elapsedtime" class=​"column btn">​ElapsedTime​</label>,​
<label id=​"skillstable_expertiserating" class=​"column btn">​ExpertiseRating​</label>,​
```

which matches the HTML:

```
</fieldset>
  <label id="fs_skillstable_heading" class="fs btn heading skillstable">Skills Table</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_Certification" class="row btn">Certification</label>
  <label id="skillstable_Compliance" class="row btn">Compliance</label>
  <label id="skillstable_Technology" class="row btn">Technology</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_version(s)" class="column btn">Version(s)</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_startdate" class="column btn">StartDate</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_enddate" class="column btn">EndDate</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_elapsedtime" class="column btn">ElapsedTime</label><br class="">
  <label id="skillstable_expertiserating" class="column btn">ExpertiseRating</label><br class="">
</fieldset>
```

however, these elements only are not registering with the `$('.btn').on('click', function() {...})` function, which has a console.log() section to show that it has been clicked.  They all have the `.btn` class, so I am totally lost here.  I am trying to make an array to use for persistence, and made a quick variable with .push() to show all the elements I have clicked on so i can use that string to make a persistent URL, but noticed that these sections only are not registering.

The generation for the elements are scoped within a self calling function `(function TCC() {...})();`, so I tried pulling them out of that function and calling them individually, but that did not work either.  I also switched the functions from .click() to .on('click', function(){}) to no avail.

[Here](http://specialorange.org/resume) is the webpage.

Comment: can you share your jQuery side too?

Comment: which additional part?  all is inline on the webpage

Comment: You have a lot of code in there, it's more than likely just some missing semi-colon or something else breaking all your JS. $('.btn').on('click', function () {}); should be working fine otherwise

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  My editor and JS Beautify and Lint couldn't find an issue, and I would assume if it was missing a semicolon; it would break it all, not just these select few. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does @marcjae 's answer highlight the issue?  I just dont know what 'bind the click event' means, and assume marcjae means that my generation line needs to be re-scoped outside of the (function TCC(){}), but am not sure

Comment: I believe it does. Since you are appending content to the DOM, after the click event handler has been been defined. So all you have to do, is add an deferred.done() after your each loops. Eg. $.each(cols, function(i) {...}).done(function(){ //Add click event handler now })

Comment: There are two $.each functions,   how would I either pull them out of the TCC() function or append .done() without having to duplicate the event handler code twice?  I would prefer to make them act the same as the rest of the sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because you bind the click event, before the "column button generator" loop. Easiest fix would be to use a "live" event

```
$('.btn').live('click',function(){...})
```

Or alternatively, create a callback for the loop and bind the click event then.

Comment: `live` is deprecated - use `on` with a selector parameter like barlasapaydin shows

Comment: @marcjae What do you mean that I 'bind the click event' before the generation loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try this; [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) usage :

Edit: @David Thomas mentioned `this.id;` will be better than `$(this).attr('id');` :

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function() {
    var whichPart = this.id;
    console.log(whichPart);
});
```

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ueHNg/8/)

Comment: For retrieving the `id` jQuery needlessly complicates things, just use `this.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You can test the sample code on following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkant/ueHNg/4/

Answer (score 0):

your page works in  chrome for me, i clicked on Expertise/skills/tools etc in the left section and it shows the links i clicked in the orange section on the right if that is what you wanted.

It works in IE if console/developer tools is opened already, it might be because you used console.log statements in your code

Refer to this

[What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Comment: click the right column subsections of 'Skills Table', not the left side