# IE issue with Jquery methods

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting an ID of an element. The codes work in FF and chrome but not IE.
Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot

```
<td id='tdID'>
    <img id='test' src='a.jpg' class='imgClass' />
</td>
```

jquery

```
$('.imgClass').click(function(){
   ip=$(this).parent().attr('id');          

   //undefined in IE
   console.log(ip);
})
```

Comment: Have you put your codes inside `$(document).ready()`? Is this your original markup?

Comment: Is this `<td>` inside a `<table>`?

Comment: `console.log` has some quirks in IE8. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8).

Comment: `console.log()` isn't supported on old versions of IE...

Comment: BTW, use `var` to define local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td>`s *must* be inside a `<table>`.  If they are not, most browsers will remove them from the DOM.  So, the `$(this).parent()` might not be the element you think.

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/cyK3h/

Comment: Try to `console.log($(this).parent().prop('nodeName'))` to see if it's the right element.

Comment: Yes, I did get a TD in console, but when I console.log(ip), it said 'empty string' +1 though

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), not [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.imgClass').on("click", function(){
   var id = $(this).parent().prop("id");          
   console.log(id);
});
```

also in case you change the markup it might be safer to use closest

```
$('.imgClass').on("click", function(){
   var id = $(this).closest("td").prop("id");          
   console.log(id);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQgAP/)