# Javascript -- "type" returns null in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

IE8 (not Firefox or Chrome) has a gripe with the following function:

```
function getCachedSortType(parsers, i) {
    return (parsers) ? parsers[i].type : '';
}
```

This is pulled as such:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    c = sortList[i][0];
                    order = sortList[i][1];
                    // fallback to natural sort since it is more robust
                    s = /n/i.test(getCachedSortType(tc.parsers, c)) ? "Numeric" : "Text";
```

Error: "'type' is null or not an object"

Every cell of the table using this sorter is populated. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: and what is `tc.parsers`? does it have a property named as the value in `c` and does that property value have a `type` property?

Answer (score 1):

This means that your `parsers` object does not include the items that your `getCachedSortType` is expecting (or `getCachedSortType` is expecting the wrong thing!).

You may want to add some additional bullet proofing:

```
function getCachedSortType(parsers, i) {
    if (parsers && parsers[i] && parsers[i].type) {
        return parsers[i].type;
    } else {
        console.log(parsers);
        throw new Error('Bad parsers format!');
    }
}
```

Comment: "'console' is undefined," states IE8.

Comment: @DanielEzraMoraff just remove that line. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8).

Comment: @DanielEzraMoraff edit your question to add the code that is generating the `tc.parsers` object and we may be able to help further.