# Retrieving JavaScript function's parameters of every webpage through addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, hook, ieaddon

I want to display javascript function's parameters of every webpage through my addon. the below javascript code is my addon code. i am using internal function hooking mechanism.

```
hookEval = eval;
eval = function (str)
{
   console.log("evals "+str);
   return hookEval(str);
}

hookWrite = document.write;
document.write = function (str)
{
   console.log("write"+str);
   return hookWrite(str);
}
```

The above code is displaying the parameters of java script functions in firefox and opera console, but in IE, sometimes it is displaying and most of the times nothing its displaying.

Why the above code is not working in IE?

Edit:console.log is working fine in ie9. it is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8) provides some information.  Console.log is problematic in IE.  There is also the issue of overwriting a builtin javascript function.  Not sure IE likes that.  That's just a guess though.  I've not researched it.

Comment: Don't consider console issue. i am aware of console issue. and i am using ie9 with console.