# JQuery animate not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bar graph that works perfectly in firefox & chrome, but doesn't in internet explorer. Anyone help me out? Thank you.
http://jsfiddle.net/FkUYf/6/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
           var top = $(document).scrollTop();
           console.log(top);
           if (top > 300) {
              $("#html, #css").animate({width:"100%"}, 2000);
              $("#javascript").animate({width:"40%"}, 2000);
              $("#php").animate({width:"50%"}, 2000);
              $("#mysql").animate({width:"30%"}, 2000);
              $("#wordpress").animate({width:"60%"}, 2000);
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: 5 `if` statements for the same conditions? Why?

Comment: IE doesn't have console.log, so that is probably crashing it before running the rest. Other than that, maybe the IE window is bigger to top never gets big enough. Also as undefined said, having the same if 5 times is just silly.

Comment: @Dave Um? IE has had a console since IE8. Anyway, working fine for me in IE10.

Comment: @Kolink, he didn't specify *which* IE, so it's possible he's using IE6 or 7. (also I thought it didn't have console.log until IE9?)

Comment: @Kolink: I got curious and found this, which seems like the reason for the ambiguity in IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: I'm using IE9...removed the console.log and now it works! Thank you Dave!

Comment: Place brackets after (top > 300) to help contain all 5 jquery statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(document).scrollTop();
            console.log(top);
           if (top > 300) {
                          $("#html, #css").animate({width:"100%"}, 2000)
                          $("#javascript").animate({width:"40%"}, 2000);
                          $("#php").animate({width:"50%"}, 2000);
                          $("#mysql").animate({width:"30%"}, 2000);
                          $("#wordpress").animate({width:"60%"}, 2000);
          }
        });
    });
```