# How do I check for undefined values in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, internet-explorer-8

I have this in my javascript:

```
console.log(filters);
console.log('----');
console.log(filters.max_price);
```

In Chrome, it shows this. This is the **expected** behavior.

```
Object {max_price: undefined, sort_by: undefined, distance: undefined, start: undefined, num: undefined}
----
undefined
```

In IE8, the log shows this:

```
LOG: Object Object
----
LOG: String
```

Why does IE8 think it is a string? I need to know if it's undefined.

I have lots of code that sets default values.

```
if(typeof filters.max_price == undefined){ //I use this technique a lot! 
    filter.max_price = 2000; 
}
```

How can I check for undefine-ds in IE8? Should I do this? This seems to work (yay...), but it seems cheap and hacky.

```
if(!filters.max_price || typeof filters.max_price == 'undefined'){
```

Is there a simple way I can do this with **underscore**?

Comment: Do you mean `undefined` as in "declared but not defined", or `undefined` as in "not declared nor defined"; two different things...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: @jurgemaister yea I know... but that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: IE8's `console` isn't really that good. It's better in later IE versions, but if you need to work in IE8, you could try using [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) instead. It'll give you more functionality for inspecting you JS data, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this approach, but it would not reduce your code a lot:

```
filters.max_price = filters.max_price || 2000;
```

This, however, would overwrite the value if it's 0. The best approach remains:

```
if(typeof filters.max_price === 'undefined'){
    // init default
}
```

Comment: Is the === better than my current version of ==? Will triple === work with IE8?

Comment: @TIMEX Triple also compares types and the type of undefined is "undefined"

Comment: It doesn't work with IE8.  if(typeof filters.max_price === 'undefined'){ ....IE8 does not catch it.

Comment: >> filters.max_price = undefined 
>> typeof filters.max_price === "undefined" 
true

Comment: `undefined` is a _falsy_ statement therefore it should evaluate to false in a conditional statement. Checking for its type is a bad way of doing things because of browser inconsistencies. `if(!filters.max_price)` is all you need.

Comment: @AndreiNemes And that returns true when max_price = 0

Comment: No it doesn't. 0 is also falsy.

Comment: @AndreiNemes yes so not-ing it is true is what I'm saying. The person wants to check for undefined and doesn't want to overwrite values like 0.

Comment: Then simply check if it's a number `if(isNaN(filters.max_price))`

Comment: Max price is a string? What's the value range then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a guard operator to set a default value:

```
filters.max_price = filters.max_price || 2000;
```

To check if the value is a number (which I supposed a price is), you can use

```
if(isNaN(filters.max_price)) {
    //enter code here
}
```

This will also filter out `undefined` as not a number.