# Jquery working fine in FF but not in IE

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have written the below code for pagination. This is working fine in FF but failing in IE :(. Can anyone of you pls let me know where I have gone wrong? Is it the $ symbol? I coulb not trace out. Can someone pls help me in finding the solution.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".content .outageinfo").hide();
    $("#alertupdate div").hide();
    $(".content .outageinfo").slice(0, 3).show();
    $("#alertupdate div").slice(0, 3).show();
    $("#prev").addClass("disabled");
    if($(".content .outageinfo").length < 4){
    $("#next").addClass("disabled");
    }


    $("#next").click(function () {
        $("#prev").removeClass("disabled");
        var items = $('.content .outageinfo:visible').hide().last();
        var radItems = $("#alertupdate .outageradio:visible").hide().last();

        var nextItems = items.nextAll().slice(0, 3);
        var nextRadItems = radItems.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

        if (nextItems.last().nextAll().length <= 3) {
            console.log(nextItems.length);
            $("#next").addClass("disabled");
            $("#prev").removeClass("disabled");
        }

        nextItems.show();
        nextRadItems.show();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function () {
        $("#next").removeClass("disabled");
        var items = $('.content .outageinfo:visible').hide().first();
        var radItems = $("#alertupdate .outageradio:visible").hide().first();

        var prevItems = items.prevAll().slice(0, 3);
        var prevRadItems = radItems.prevAll(".outageradio").slice(0, 3);
     //   console.log(prevRadItems);
     //   console.log(prevItems.first());
     //   console.log(prevItems.first().prevAll());
     //   console.log(prevItems.first().prevAll().length)
        if (prevItems.last().prevAll().length == 0 ) {

            $("#next").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#prev").addClass("disabled");
        }

        prevItems.show();
        prevRadItems.show();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Which version of IE you are using ? Press `F12` & go to `Console` menu And then refresh the page. You can find what errors occured & in which line.,

Comment: Why are you using noConflict? Do you have more than one library that's using the $ symbol, or mixed versions of jQuery?

Comment: F12 is not showing any error. Im using IE8.

Comment: In IE 8 and above means, Press `F12` & go to `Console` menu And then refresh the page. You can find what errors occured & in which line

Comment: We are using mootools also..

Comment: @Manikandan...tried that but still no errors

Comment: @PhanimadhaviVasantala Bences' answer is correct. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once for more information.

Comment: @PhanimadhaviVasantala : Delete all the js code & put some `alert` then check., like `$(function(){  alert('load');  });`... First ensure the jquery is working or not., ** I guess you are missing to call some jquery links.,

Answer (score 2):

console.log() kills IE below 8. In IE 8 and 9 only works if developer tools are opened.