# Console undefined issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I understand that IE only treats **console** as an object if the debug window is open. If the debug window is not open, it treats console as undefined.

Which is why I decided to add an **if** check like this :

```
        if(console)
            console.log('removing child');
```

My understanding is that if **console** is undefined it will skip the **console.log**. However in IE8 the **if(console)** line passes and I get an undefined exception like before at **console.log**. This is weird.

Is there a way around this?
and how do you code console in your code so that it runs on all three browsers?

Comment: console not support in IE8,remove it work in FF,chrome,safari,iE9

Comment: @JamesDonnelly You should read the question again. It's not about the console not being defined in IE but console.log not defined in IE8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add the following to the if clause:

```
if (console && console.log) {
    console.log('removing child');
}
```

Or write a log wrapper around the console.log function like this.

```
window.log = function () {
    if (this.console && this.console.log) {
        this.console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
log("This method is bulletproof", window, arguments");
```

And here is a jsfiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/joquery/4Ugvg/

Comment: This should log an Array, why don't you apply the sliced arguments to `console.log` ?

Comment: +1 I get the problem for IE8 and help me fast !

Answer (score 4):

You could set `console.log` to an empty function

```
if(typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = {
        log : function () {}
    }
}
```

This way you have to bother only once.l

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the console exists

```
window.console && console.log('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition like this instead, as if console is not supported it will throw undefined not false;

```
if(typeof console !== "undefined") {
console.log('removing child');
}
```

However to prevent having to wrap all your console log statemnts I would just put this snippet in your code. This will stop IE throwing any error

```
if(typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = {
        log: function() { },
        debug: function() { },
        ...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what the type of console is, and also what the type of console.log is. You might want to check this link:

[What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

Check more information on the same: http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/