# Loop not doing anything

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-chrome-app

I am trying to loop through an array of html object and add a click event listener to every one of them.
Reason for this is CSP.

problem is: it doesn't do it, no errors.. nothing...

Please help before I go insane.

```
var linkButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("navItem");
for(var i=0;i<linkButtons.length;i++){
  linkButtons[index].addEventListener("click",function()console.log("e.e");});
}
```

Comment: The code you quote has a syntax error - missing `{`. That said, what is the context? Where are you calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function()console` -> `function(){console` and make sure the document is loaded.

Corrected:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var linkButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("navItem");
    for(var i=0;i<linkButtons.length;i++){
        linkButtons[index].addEventListener("click",function(){console.log("e.e");});
    }
});
```

Comment: Argh, hahahahhaa can't believe a typo was kicking my ass >.<.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, any idea on why this only works with the console open? When the console isn't open, the listener doesn't get attached

Comment: I've noticed that in some browsers, the console does not _exist_ when it's closed, and it causes errors. Getting rid of you `console.log`'s or [overriding it so that it works anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17104745/1913729) should solve this.

Comment: I's a chrome app, I don't know if that matters

Comment: In production, minifying your code and getting rid of the logs is best, but if you override your console like the link I posted, it shouldn't cause a problem to keep them.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks a lot ^_^ I'll try it when I get the chance, the reason I log  a lot is to make sure everything works/debugging (I take em all out at the end