# Why on IE 8 that a change event on input is not propagated to the form element?

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, dom-events

I thought a change event would propagate from the input element to the form element in general?

On Chrome, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gjatW/13/

But on IE 8, no `console.log` will be invoked: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gjatW/13/show/

(note that we have to type something and focus out of the input box for the `change` event to fire, rather than individual keystroke)

(we have to use the jshell.net to look at the resultant frame, because IE 8 doesn't render jsfiddle.net correctly).

---

Further details:

If we bind it on the `input` element, then we see the `console.log` on both Chrome and IE 8:

http://jsfiddle.net/gjatW/12/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/gjatW/12/show/

If using jQuery, then it works on both Chrome and IE 8 even if we bind on the form element.  But the question is, I thought IE 8 supports bubbling, so why is the change event not bubbled to the form element if we are using DOM level 0 `onchange` handler?

http://jsfiddle.net/gjatW/10/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/gjatW/10/show/

Comment: Does IE 8 have `console.log` at all?

Comment: if you open up the Developer's tool

Comment: Ah, [OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8).