# jquery Console.log not shown its output in Internet Explorer debugger

Tags: jquery

I have a jqGrid and on change event I do something. Within this event I want to show in the console something but this message is not shown in the console. For example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#_jqGrid').on('change', function () {
        console.log('jqGrid changed!');
        $.event.trigger('Added');
    });
});
```

Why is the message not shown in Internet Explorer console with debugging tools?

Comment: Which version of IE?  You may need to open the debug tools and the refresh the page (so that the page loads with the tools open).

Comment: The console object isn't created until you open DevTools ; see original post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Comment: IE7 has this issue to...although most of the time it should just throw an error saying `Console is undefined` or some crap.

Comment: @tymeJV: I think even IE9 has the same issue.

Comment: `console` is not supported by IE

Comment: @Satpal: Yes it is.  You just need to have the dev tools opened *before* the page loads.

Comment: I have i.e 10 and i have dev tools opened. Even if I put an alert instead, alert is ignored...maybe because it is whithin an event handler?

Comment: @user304602: Have you tried to trigger that event?  Have you tried to change `#_jqGrid`?

Comment: Yes, the event is triggered correctly.

Comment: @user304602: I've never used `jqGrid`, but maybe it overrides your event handlers with its own?