# Jquery execute url

Tags: jquery, url, post, delete-row

could you please check if this the right code to do what I pretend? I just want to click on a button, delete the record and return to the same page where I was before. The following sample is working on IE9 and Chrome, but not on IE8.

I´ve got a table with rows, inside a DIV (#page_content). At the end of each row I have a button that allows to delete that record. The button code is the following:

```
<a class="delete" href="pages/roomwizard/roomwizard_delete.asp?id=<%=Rs("id")%>"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete record"/></a>
```

The delete function is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // it does the job!!!

$('#page_content .delete').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var url_delete = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post(url_delete);

    $('#content').load(url_back); // main div, with #page_content inside

});
```

As I said, in IE9 and Chrome is working. I don´t know if this is the right way to do it. In IE8, when the button is clicked it still works, but it opens a blank page or stays at the same page (with preventDefault).

Comment: this code seems to be ok, so perhaps there's something else causing an error. Perhaps a console log? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: Like I said, it works. But not with the IE8. I think it have something to do with the cache. When I´m using the IE9, the record is deleted and when it returns to the previous page the record is no longer there. With the IE8 it doesn´t happen anything, but when I reopen the browser the data it is update.

Comment: The code is now working. I´ve updated the code with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a missing semi-colon after the "load" method, you could try returning false as well as preventing the default behaviour. Something like this:

```
$('#page_content .delete').click(function (e) {    
    var url_delete = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post(url_delete, function () {
        $('#content').load(url_back); // main div, with #page_content inside
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;    
});
```

Comment: The semi-colon and the preventDefault are there, on the original code ;) already try with the the return false, but nothing happens.

Comment: @ziba see my edit - try reloading the content AFTER the $.post request has returned.

Comment: also works in IE9, not in IE8. If I press the F5 to refresh the page the record remains there ... It only desappears when the browser is reopened :/

Comment: @ziba sounds like a caching issue which is beyond the scope of this question - but try appending a cache buster to the end of your URLs - $.post(url_delete + '&_t=' + new Date().getTime(), func...

Comment: I´ve found the solution! Place this code at the beginning: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Comment: @ziba awesome! that's basically telling jQuery to do what I did manually in my previous comment. glad you got it sorted. don't forget to mark this as the answer if i helped solve your question :)