# jQuery Function not working - function unidentified

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run the following code below and the `console.log()` is giving me unidentified why?

**Function:**

```
function postTitleCheck(){

       $('.postForm').on('blur', '#post_title', function(e){

            console.log(urlCheck());
});
}


function urlCheck() {

 $(".postForm").on('blur', '#post_url_link', function (e) {

        var url      = base_url + 'admin/page/urlCheck';

        var data = {
            moviesparx_website_id : $('#post_url_link').data("id"),
            post_title            : $('#post_url_link').val()
        };

        e.preventDefault();

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data ,

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {

                if(resp == '')
                {

                }else{
                    alert(resp);
                }
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply this because you cant pass a event action in a function you can trigger a event but not pass as a parameter

```
$('.postForm').on('blur', '#post_title', function(e){

   $(".postForm #post_url_link").blur(); 
    //or
   $(".postForm #post_url_link").trigger('blur'); 

});

$(".postForm").on('blur', '#post_url_link', function (e) {

        var url      = base_url + 'admin/page/urlCheck';

        var data = {
            moviesparx_website_id : $('#post_url_link').data("id"),
            post_title            : $('#post_url_link').val()
        };

        e.preventDefault();

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data ,

            type: 'POST',
            success: function (resp) {

                if(resp == '')
                {

                }else{
                    alert(resp);
                }
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` is not standard JavaScript object. It's defined by browser it self (ie. Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug). So i.e. in IE You will get undefined. For IE compatibility You can take a use of this answer:

[What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

`urlCheck` isn't returning a value -- it's just calling another function!  So, javascript says it's undefined.  It's just like if you had this:

```
function foo(bar) {
    // no code here
}

console.log( foo('bar') );
```