# Console.log in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, console.log

I have below piece of code, which, when tested, does not work in IE8. I have it running on IE11 and Chrome and it runs perfectly. I have debugged the code in IE8 which points at "console.log as a problem area.
The most interesting thing is that when I start debugging JS in IE8 - it kicks it and this piece of code start working. Then again, on leaving debugging, closing and re-opening file - same story until you get into debugging))).

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.Response input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        console.log(this.value)
        if (this.value == 'Y' || this.value == 'NA' || this.value == 'NS') {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("background", "#AADDB2"); 
        } else if (this.value == 'N') {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("background", "#FFC5C5"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Would appreciate yr help. 
PS. Unfortunately, user kind of "must" use IE8 and upgrading is not an option(((.
Thank you in advance)))

Comment: IE8 chokes on console commands unless the dev tools are open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can prevent ie8 errors on console.log with

```
if (!window.console){ console = {log: function() {}} };
```

Comment: But this will prevent the log from working in IE8 if the dev tool is opened after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some safety code to define `console` if it doesn't exist:

```
if (typeof console === "undefined" || typeof console.log === "undefined") {
    console.log = function(log_message) {
        alert(log_message);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, no. User respond to an electronic checklist - he clicks and gets Alert Messages ))))

Comment: oh well I thought this was for debugging. In that case, just leave the alert line out, and the function will just do nothing.