# In IE 8 forEach not work, how to change this code to work

Tags: javascript, each

I have this code in JS, which doesn't work in IE8.

```
Offices.forEach(function(trade) {

            console.log('Id for this trade is: '+trade.ID);

           });
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Show some effort please, at least google.

Comment: console.log, its not supported in ie8 if you dont open dev tools , check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` is not supported in IE8 (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). Here's the shim:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
    }
  };
}
```

Or you could use a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#each) which has its own cross-browser implementation.